# How can a barbarian deal with the elite affixes?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

When I was levelling my demon hunter I was able to use vault to quickly get away from an area where damage was happening or smoke screen to break freezes and jailer cages.

I've had some difficulty with arcane, jailer, frozen as they can really stack up quickly.

I do use ignore pain to great effect, but that doesn't help against everything.

What can I do on a barbarian to counter the various elite affixes?  Which will break freezes and jailers?

Comment: Displaying your current Barbarian skill tree would really help us coming up with tips and improvements for you.

Comment: @doomy In keeping the answer applicable to a wider audience, general tips and strategies are the most helpful for me.  I could just take the gold from my L60 and buy awesome gear.  I'm looking for a more general approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrath of the Berserker is your go to skill in times of emergency.  While in that mode, you are immune to control effects (I believe this is the only barbarian skill that breaks control effects).  However, don't pop it as soon as a fight starts, you'll want to save it for emergencies due to its long cool down.

For more less pressing situations, leap is a great way to escape being trapped.  Its pretty fast recharge, and if you time it right, you can be mid air while the frozen triggers and it'll miss completely.

Typically, your best bet is to maneuver carefully and just be constantly on the move and avoid those effects completely.  Sometimes this is very hard to do if the enemy has jail and vortex, in those situations you'll have to stagger your leap and ignore pain to survive the long stretches (or pop WToB).

Comment: I am happy that you mentioned ignore pain, because that has been a huge standby for me in those situations.  Mobility is key for melee... you can not stand still and fight against most elite packs on inferno.  That being said, the barbarian has an amazing charge skill.

Answer (score 1):

Use the passive Juggernaut skill.

Comment: Hey, Xena, thanks for the tip; any chance you might be able to flesh this out a bit more?  Just telling us to use a single skill doesn't really help anyone much at all.

Comment: Since it unlocks at level 50, I don't know how helpful it'll be for someone levelling.